# ExpansionTile background color not changing as expected

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I have a List with ExpensionTiles in a sidebar navigation.

The active (selected) tile should have some background.

The following code leads to the behaviour:

- the color of the container changes when isActive changes.
- the color of the title changes when isActive changes.
- the color of the ExpansionTile **does not change** when isActive changes

**... but when hitting the hot-reload button backgroundColor and collapsedBackgroundColor are getting updated.**

Anyone an idea what is the problem here?

```
ListTileTheme(
      dense: true,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          color: isActive ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(title, style: isActive ? titleStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.blue) : titleStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black)),
              iconColor: isActive ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
              initiallyExpanded: isActive,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              collapsedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
              maintainState: false,
              backgroundColor: isActive ? Colors.pink  : Colors.transparent,
              collapsedBackgroundColor: isActive ? Colors.pink : Colors.transparent,
...
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```